# How can i append form data to the url on the site?

Tags: url, append, form-data

i have the following site
http://www.acswebnetworks.com/keithhudgins

I want a form or text box where someone can enter a code like
kh158534
and when they submit it goes to
http://www.acswebnetworks.com/keithhudgins/kh158534

Everything i try either puts a ?= or something like that

Comment: Maybe you should start by reading some documentation on basic HTML forms and URL manipulation. `?=` is not "something like that", it is one of the basic mechanisms fro transmitting information from one page to another.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which language you are using and I'm not sure wether your are doing the right thing the right way or not. But anyways if you are using PHP you can simply use concatenation operator (.)

```
$defaultText = "http://www.acswebnetworks.com/keithhudgins/";
$defaultTextWithId = $defaultText . "kh15834";
```

And here you can submit the form with the new URL